# Working on Adventureworks2014, not joining correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Using SqlServer 2014.

Below is my good and bad code. I am trying to query the HumanResources.Employee db, and include two things with it, the most recent pay upgrade in pay from the HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory in the form of "most recent date", and the First, Middle, and Last Names from the Person.Person file.

I was able to query the employee data and include the names successfully.

```
select b.*,(a.FirstName +' '+ isnull(a.MiddleName,'')+' '+a.LastName) as WHOLE_NAME
from Person.Person a
join HumanResources.Employee b
on a.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID
```

I was able to then figure out how to get the correct date format out of the pay history file...

```
Select Convert(VarChar(10),ModifiedDate,101) as Date 
From HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory
```

I know that I can find the MAX date for each pay upgrade like this:

```
Select BusinessEntityID, MAX(ModifiedDate) as MostRecent
From HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
Group By BusinessEntityID
```

But when I try to combine three tables, my brain pretty much melts and I keep blowing it. Here is my mess:

```
Select Convert(VarChar(10),c.ModifiedDate,101) as Date, b.*,(a.FirstName +' '+ isnull(a.MiddleName,'')+' '+a.LastName) as WHOLE_NAME
From Person.Person a inner join
HumanResources.Employee b on a.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID
inner join 
(Select BusinessEntityID, MAX(ModifiedDate) as MostRecent
From HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
Group By BusinessEntityID)
HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory c
on c.businessEntityID = a.BusinessEntityID
```

Can you help me fix this final three-table join attempt? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change this `Convert(VarChar(10),c.ModifiedDate,101) as Date` to this `Convert(VarChar(10),c.MostRecent,101) as Date` (since you have named the column you are referencing `as MostRecent`)
- Change your alias on your derived table join to simply `c`

Whole query:

```
SELECT Convert(VarChar(10),c.MostRecent,101) as Date, 
       b.*,
      (a.FirstName +' '+ isnull(a.MiddleName,'')+' '+a.LastName) as WHOLE_NAME
FROM Person.Person a 
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee b on a.BusinessEntityID = b.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN (SELECT BusinessEntityID, MAX(ModifiedDate) as MostRecent
            FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
            GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
           ) c on c.businessEntityID = a.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Aaron. Weird. So the 2nd Inner Join with the Max Function is given the "c" assignment outside the parenthesis on the bottom line. Ok, I see that. I need to think about the fact that you changed it to most recent, since at first I thought that using MostRecent in that lower select statement didn't necessarily declare it.

Comment: @hitbid No problem.  The technical terms for that `JOIN` are *nested select* and/or *derived table*.  The important one there is *derived table*, as you are essentially creating a table for the outer query to reference.  Because of this.. any aliases that you give columns in your derived tables, will be seen as the actual column names in your outer query.

Comment: @hitbid Another way to think of it would be to make a temp table out of your derived table, then simply replace the whole join with `INNER JOIN #TEMP t on t.businessEntityID = a.BusinessEntityID`.  Now, any column you wanted to select from `#TEMP`, you would select by it's column name in `#TEMP`.  It is the same logic happening with the derived table, you're simply doing all of that in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this.  You can do 2 easy joins and then MAX() the last pay raise from the pay history table. I don't think you need to touch the employee dept history table.

```
SELECT c.*
    , a.businessentityid
    , FirstName + ISNULL(middlename, '') + lastname AS fullname
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(b.ratechangedate), 101) AS last_pay_increase
FROM person.person a
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory b
    ON b.BusinessEntityID = a.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee c
    ON c.BusinessEntityID = a.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY c.BusinessEntityID
    , c.NationalIDNumber
    , c.LoginID
    , c.OrganizationNode
    , c.OrganizationLevel
    , c.JobTitle
    , c.BirthDate
    , c.MaritalStatus
    , c.Gender
    , c.HireDate
    , c.SalariedFlag
    , c.VacationHours
    , c.SickLeaveHours
    , c.CurrentFlag
    , c.rowguid
    , c.ModifiedDate
    , a.businessentityid
    , FirstName + ISNULL(middlename, '') + lastname
```